# What is the most limited and expensive resource in a computer?

Tags: performance, networking, resources, compression, computer-science

What is the most expensive and limited resource in a computer today?

Is it the **CPU**? Maybe the **memory** or as I was told the **bandwidth** (Or something entirely different)?

Does that mean that a computer should do everything to use that resource more efficiently,
including putting more load on other resources?

*For example by compressing files, do we put more load on the CPU, so the file can be transmitted over
the network faster?*

I think I know the answer to that, but I would like to hear it from someone else, please provide an explanation.

Comment: This question is really off-topic for this site as it's more of a discussion with no single answer possible.  See [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Then where is the appropriate place for discussions?

Comment: Depends on what you need it to do.

Comment: The time you spend as a human is the most limited and expensive resource. Don't bother optimizing unless and until you can determine that it would be worth your time.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more costly resource that you left out -- Design and Programming.

I answer a lot of questions here.  Rarely do I say "beef up the hardware".  I usually say "redesign or rewrite".

Most hardware improvements are measured in percentages.  Cleaver redesigns are measured in multiples.

A complex algorithm can be replaced by a big table lookup.  -- "Speed" vs "space".

"Your search returned 8,123,456 results, here are the first 10" -- You used to see things like that from search engines.  Now it says "About 8,000,000 results" or does not even say anything. -- "Alter the user expectations" or "Get rid of the bottleneck!".

One time I was looking at why a program was so slow.  I found that 2 lines of code were responsible for 50% of the CPU consumed.  I rewrote those 2 lines into about 20, nearly doubling the speed.  This is an example of how to focus the effort to efficiently use the programmer.

Before SSDs, large databases were severely dominated by disk speed.  SSDs shrank that by a factor of 10, but disk access is still a big problem.

Many metrics in computing have followed Moore's law.  But one hit a brick wall -- CPU speed.  That has only doubled in the past 20 years.  To make up for it, there are multiple CPUs/cores/threads.  But that requires much more complex code.  Most products punt -- and simply use a single 'cpu'.

"Latency" vs "throughput" -- These two are mostly orthogonal.  The former measures elapsed time, which is limited by the speed of light, etc.  The latter measures how much data -- fiber optics is much "fatter" than a phone wire.